# Is there a way to read the printer LCD screen into OctoPi?

Tags: octoprint, raspberry-pi, lcd-screen, octopi

Is there a way to 'read' the LCD screen from a 3D printer as is, using a Raspberry Pi?

I'd like to connect the printers LCD screen to my Raspberry Pi to be able to view the screen as is, in OctoPi, in an identical way as looking at the physical LCD. This could serve as some kind of viewing console and can be helpful to determine remotely what the printer status is, for example when it's in a Shutdown mode, disconnected or unresponsive.

Optionally being able to control it as on the screen would be great but I don't think that's even remotely easy to achieve. Are there any projects that attempt to achieve this for only viewing or viewing and controlling?

Comment: A similar question was asked in a Discord group; if I remember correctly, it depends on the printer model and the interface on the LCD screen.

Comment: Wasn't there a plugin that does that?

Comment: As far as I know there is only one that shows the printer messages from the M117 or M118 G-code https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/DisplayLayerProgress/. I'm not aware of another one for the whole screen.